# Samba/VM is spamming DNS requests

Tags: domain-name-system, samba

**My Setup:**

Linux VM (Alpine) in Virtual Box on a Windows 10 host. Samba (4.8.12) runs within the VM and the host has the samba directory mounted as a network drive by its IP i.e. `\\192.168.1.22\wipster`. Both the host and the VM have a lease so the IPs never change. The Samba config is quit simple:

```
[global]

socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
max xmit = 65535
deadtime = 15

workgroup = mygroup.local

server string = %h Server

server role = standalone server

hosts allow = 192.168.1.110

dns proxy = no

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   path = /home/wipster
   force user = wipster
   force group = wipster
```

**The Problem:**

Whenever I copy data over to the network drive it will get slow quickly and then stop completely.

In Wireshark I can see, that as soon as I start to copy data the VM sends a lot of DNS requests, demanding the IP for the host of the VM itself (192.168.1.22 -> 8.8.8.8). The requests go on for minutes after stopping to copy data. I can only navigate again in the network drive after the requests stop. The responses obviously give a *failure* or a *refuse* because it's just a random hostname for my VM.

**What I have tried:**

I added `127.0.0.1 <hostname-of-vm>` to the hosts file which didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve the problem, although I don't understand what was going on. If someone comes up with an explanation I will mark it as the correct answer.

After writing the question I noticed that it might be a problem that I connect the network drive by the IP of the VM. I added the hostname to the hosts file in Windows and connect the network drive by that name. Afterwards the DNS request spam has gone away.